# PostgreSQL find the minimum

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have 2 tables:

eomployee:

```
e_id  | firstname | lastname  
-------+-----------+-----------
 10100 | Mark      | Stevens
 10101 | Alex      | Watts
 10102 | Hannah    | Burton
```

and works_on:

```
employee_e_id | product_prod_nr | hours 
---------------+-----------------+-------
         10100 | 66000           |    40
         10100 | 77211           |    37
         10101 | 90210           |    67
```

I now want to get the e_id, firstname, lastname, hours of the person who is working the least hours. This is just sample data from the 2 tables.
I tried ti get it with limit 1, but that does not work when i have 2 people working 1 hour for example.

Comment: Do you want the row with the least hours (37) or do you want the least summed up hours (10100 is working 40 + 37 = 77 hours and so 10101 is working less)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use window functions:

```
SELECT e_Id, firstname, lastname, hours
FROM (SELECT e.*,
             MIN(hours) OVER () as min_hours
      FROM eomployee e JOIN
           works_on w
           ON e.e_id = w.employee_e_id
     ) ew
WHERE hours = min_hours;
```

Answer (score 0):

try like below by using window function

```
with cte as
(
select e.e_id,
e.firstname,e.lastname,w.hours,row_number() over(order by w.hours asc) rn
from eomployee e join works_on w on e.e_id=w.employee_e_id
) select * from cte where rn=1
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want the row with the least hours (= 37 in your example):

```
SELECT
    e.e_id,
    e.firstname,
    e.lastname,
    w.hours
FROM 
    eomployee e 
JOIN works_on w ON e.e_id = w.employee_e_id
ORDER BY w.hours
LIMIT 1
```

If you want to get the row for cumulative working hours (in your example "10100" is working 37+ 40 = 77 hours):

```
SELECT
    e_Id, firstname, lastname, hours
FROM (
    SELECT
        e.e_id,
        e.firstname,
        e.lastname,
        w.hours,
        SUM(hours) OVER (PARTITION BY e_id) as cum
    FROM 
        eomployee e 
    JOIN works_on w ON e.e_id = w.employee_e_id
) s
ORDER BY cum
LIMIT 1
```

[demo:db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_9.6&fiddle=8af51a7a957e110239be585c003d2119)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT e.*,
       max_hours_row.*
FROM eomployee e
INNER JOIN
  (SELECT employee_e_id,
          MIN(hours) AS time_min
   FROM works_on
   GROUP BY employee_e_id ) AS max_hours_row ON max_hours_row.employee_e_id = e.e_id
```